# How can i query and efficiently store 50 million REST API records to build a data lake

Tags: python, database, rest, salesforce, psycopg2

The problem use case is simple.

I want to query more than 50M records from Salesforce through REST API. It is a part of effort to gather data from multiple sources to fuse them together later which can be fed into a ML model.
This data i want to store into a database or a parquet file, from where i can perform the next steps.

Now, Salesforce on a rest api query on such a huge data size for an object, will return something like

```
 {"totalsize":50000000, "done":false, 
"nextrecordUrl":"/services/data/v49.0/a1000xxxxxx-2000",
 "records":[here the data of query remains of the 2000 batch that was returned]}
```

The nextRecordUrl simple gives the url to query the next batch od 2000(max batch size that can be returned by salesforce, however no gurantee on this number).
So i am simple running a loop until there is no more nextRecordUrl to get the entire set of data.

Current approach looks like this:

```
    read the data = query(api)
    while "done" is not True:
          read the "records" part of the json 
          load it into Database ( using psycopg2 )
          again read data = query( nextRecordUrl )
          read value of "done"
```

My question is, how can i speed this operation up?
Considering even if every loop takes 2 second to complete, this will still take 16-17 hours at best and we might need to run it every fortnight to keep up the latest data as reflected in the application ( salesforce ), not to mention the database timeout error or the memory errors I have to deal with.

Any suggestions?

edit :
current approach is like this :

```
sf = salesforce () # simple_salesforce library connection
df = pandas dataframe
sqlalc_engine = sqlalchemy engine
# query the first batch here then this loop start
while True:
            if num_batches == 1:
                current_df = df
            else:
                current_df = pd.DataFrame(lstRecords)
                #print(current_df.columns)
                current_df = current_df.drop(['attributes'], axis=1)

            print(f"next record URL is :{nextRecordsUrl}, || batch no is : {num_batches}")
            print(f"Loading batch : {num_batches} | records count : {current_df.shape[0]}")

            #this line i am using to insert records into DB
            current_df.to_sql(table_name, con=sqlalc_engine, schema='', if_exists='append', index=False)

            print(f"{num_batches} is loaded to DB")
            num_batches+=1

            if completed:
                #no more records
                break

            # get next batch of records
            records = sf.query_more(nextRecordsUrl, identifier_is_url=True)
            lstRecords = records.get('records')
            nextRecordsUrl = records.get('nextRecordsUrl')

            # set running check for next loop
            completed = records.get('done')
```

Comment: You need to show more of the basic processing outline. For example are you inserting individual records into the database or do you bulk upload the full batch each time? That might be the biggest bottleneck, not the API query speed

Comment: Note that in older versions of `psycopg2`, `executemany` does not work how you expect (you might think you're doing a bulk upload with this, but you're not) and you'd need to use `execute_values`. Or you can create bigger batches on the backend (200k for example) and use a `COPY` command. Too many unknowns but this is definitely where I would focus

Comment: I have added in the post my approach

Answer (score 1):

Put a WHERE clause in your query to not fetch everything every time.

`SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate >= 2024-02-25T01:23:45T` (use the last successful job's start timestamp. Start, not end, to make sure you don't have gaps!). Or there are special [not-really-constants](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) that let you  write `WHERE LastModifiedDate >= LAST_WEEK`.

That should cut your time significantly. How often the data changes? Say 5%? Are there any other filters that would make sense to apply or do you literally need everything.

Another thing is that you are using the synchronous API (send request, wait, process results, send next request...). There's asynchronous version that might be a better fit: [Bulk API 2.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_intro.htm). You fire a request and periodically ask "is it done yet". SF starts to produce result files with up to 10K rows each and you could pull them even in multiple threads (assuming the rest of your app can handle multithreading nicely, might be that the next bottleneck will be the locking in the local database?).

If you really want to craft the requests by hand there are some resources: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_code_curl_walkthrough.htm but I'd be tempted to use [`simple salesforce`](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce?tab=readme-ov-file#using-bulk) to do the heavy lifitng?

Another bonus is that bulk API will let you use [PK chunking](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/async_api_headers_enable_pk_chunking.htm) to further effectively cut the results into files. It means that say if given "chunk" of 100-250K records has only 5 that meet your query conditions - the resulting file for that chunk will have only that 5 instead of 10K you specified as batch size. But hey, will be generated faster.